# How to make a jcarousel item move/sort?

Tags: views, javascript

I have a view that loads a content type's images in a jcarousel format. They are arranged to show 3 items at a time.

1. How do you make any item clicked/selected on the jcarousel move to
   the middle?
2. Is it possible to customize the jcarousel to do a $_GET and read
   from the url as to use this as the image to be set in the middle?
3. If #2 is possible, can this be implemented via AJAX/jquery?